# Ruby. Merging a nested hash without overwriting

Tags: ruby, hash, merge, nested

I have a nested hash:

```
{
  ["X", 1, 2, 3]=> {
    ["X", "O", 2, 3]=> {
      ["X", "O", "X", 3]=>["X", "O", "X", "O"]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to merge a given nested hash:

```
{
  ["X", 1, 2, 3]=> {
    ["X", "O", 2, 3]=> {
      ["X", "O", 2, "X"] => ["X", "O", "O", "X"]
    }
  }
}
```

such that:

```
{
  ["X", 1, 2, 3]=> {
    ["X", "O", 2, 3]=> {
      ["X", "O", "X", 3]=>["X", "O", "X", "O"],
      ["X", "O", 2, "X"] => ["X", "O", "O", "X"]
    }
  }
}
```

What's the best way?

The hashes I'll be merging will have an equivalent key at an arbitrary depth of nested-ness. The value of the last nested hash will always be different from all the other hashes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593. Without an example of what you tried it looks like you want us to write the code for you, not fix the problem with your code.

Comment: You don't want to see what I tried.

Comment: @Adzz: Even if doesn't run, even if it's pretty, it's still good to see that you tried something, and how you tried it.

Comment: Yes we do want to see it. That's how we help you best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that all the duplicate keys have values that are Hashes, you can use a recursive [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) with block :

```
def deep_merge(h1,h2)
  h1.merge(h2){|k,v1,v2| deep_merge(v1,v2) }
end
```

With your example :

```
{["X", 1, 2, 3]=>
  {["X", "O", 2, 3]=>
    {["X", "O", "X", 3]=>["X", "O", "X", "O"],
     ["X", "O", 2, "X"]=>["X", "O", "O", "X"]}}}
```

**NOTE:** This method doesn't work in the general case, and shouldn't be used for anything else than the structure defined in the question. It will fail for `deep_merge({a:1},{a:2})`.

If you don't have information about the nested keys and values :

```
def deep_merge(h1,h2)
  h1.merge(h2){|k,v1,v2| v1.is_a?(Hash) && v2.is_a?(Hash) ? deep_merge(v1,v2) : v2}
end
```

In case of a conflict with values that aren't both Hashes, the second value will overwrite the first one.

Both methods return a new hash, and do not modify either h1 or h2.

NOTE: This method is available in [Rails](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge).

Comment: Suppose `h1 = { a: { b: :c, d: :e } }; h2 = { a: { b: :c, f: :g } }`. Should this not produce `{ a: { b: :c, d: :e, b: :c, f: :g } }`? Your code #1 raises an exception.

Comment: The first method uses the information `The value of the last nested hash will always be different from all the other hashes.` from the OP. Your example doesn't sastify this property, so the second method is the one you want. It returns `{:a=>{:b=>:c, :d=>:e, :f=>:g}}`, as expected.