# How to merge hash of hash without replacing first hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Consider two hashes:

```
     h1 =  {a: 1, b: 2, d: {g: 7, h: 6}}
     h2 =  {a: 1, b: 2, d: {m: 4, n: 5}}
```

I was trying merge both hashes as:

```
h1.merge(h2)
```

Result: {:a=>1, :b=>2, :d=>{:m=>4, :n=>5}}

Can someone guide me to get a hash like:

```
{:a=>1, :b=>2, :d=>{:m=>4, :n=>5, :g=>7, :h=>6}}
```

I had tried using *deep_merge* as suggested by some of other answers which didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) with a block:

```
h1.merge(h2) do |k, v1, v2|
  v1.is_a?(Hash) && v2.is_a?(Hash) ? v1.merge(v2) : v2
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`deep_merge` works just fine, but it needs to be defined.

## Plain Ruby

```
class Hash
  def deep_merge(h2)
    merge(h2) { |_, v1, v2| v1.is_a?(Hash) && v2.is_a?(Hash) ? v1.deep_merge(v2) : v2 }
  end
end

h1 =  { a: 1, b: 2, d: { g: 7, h: 6 } }
h2 =  { a: 1, b: 2, d: { m: 4, n: 5 } }

h1.deep_merge(h2)
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :d=>{:g=>7, :h=>6, :m=>4, :n=>5}}
```

This method definition has the advantage of being recursive, and working with Hashes of any depth (see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109599/ruby-merging-a-nested-hash-without-overwriting/41109737?noredirect=1#comment69429458_41109737) from yesterday).

Finally, if you want the exact same output as in your example, you need `h2.merge(h1)`:

```
h2.deep_merge(h1) #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :d=>{:g=>7, :h=>6, :m=>4, :n=>5}}
h1.deep_merge(h2) #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :d=>{:m=>4, :n=>5, :g=>7, :h=>6}}
```

## Rails 3 & 4

`Hash#deep_merge` comes with [Rails 3 & 4](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge).

If you use Rails, there's no need to define anything before using `deep_merge`

If you have Rails installed, and want to use `deep_merge` in plain Ruby scripts, you can use :

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
h1.deep_merge(h2)
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :d=>{:g=>7, :h=>6, :m=>4, :n=>5}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I Got to know deep_merge was deprecated in rails 5

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. Rails sure is a moving target! By the way, the accepted answer doesn't work in the general case. `h1 =  {a: {b: {c: 1} } }; h2 =  {a: {b: {d: 2} } }` doesn't get merged correctly for example.